# I've used my Sony PlayStation Eye with several desktop apps. Why doesn't iChat see it?

Tags: snow-leopard, ichat

I have a [Sony PlayStation Eye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_Eye) USB camera and microphone.

I have successfully used it on my Mac Pro desktop with several video application ([iShowU HD](http://store.shinywhitebox.com/ishowuhd/main.html) for example).

However, although iChat will recognise the microphone it will not work with the camera, see screen shot.

[image: iChat]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://webcam-osx.sourceforge.net/
Good luck!
:-)